# Comparing arrays until I have a unique array

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I have the following multidimensional array called `$existing_combinations`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 21
            [3] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 9
        )

)
```

I then generate a new array (`$new_combination`) which has a combination of the same set of values. Example:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 21
    [3] => 9
)
```

I then test if `$new_combination` exists in `$existing_combinations` with the following in the hope that I will end with a unique combination in `$new_combination`:

```
foreach($existing_combinations as $key => $combination){
    while($new_combination == $combination){
        $new_combination = generateNewCombination();
    }
}
```

The problem is that if `$new_combination` matches an array that is not at index 0, then when I generate a new combination I am at risk of this matching a `$combination` that has already been tested against (and will not be tested again).

Sorry if this is a simple one but I'm struggling to think of how I can ensure `$new_combination` will always end up unique.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use in_array in this case, because php  compares  arrays as value. So, the code can be:

```
while(in_array($new_combination = generateNewCombination(), $existing_combinations));

print_r($new_combination);
```

Comment: That is about as compact as it gets for generating and checking for a new unique array in one shot. If we're generating two-digit triplets and presumably appending the new combo to the existing array, the `while` will result in an infinite loop after the 1000000 iterations have exhausted all unique combinations. May never become an issue in practice, but then again I have no idea what the use case here is.

Comment: the code you wrote shows only condition to test new value but not algorithm of make. where is else?

Comment: I've only written about verifying if the new combination is unique.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the below before realizing that `in_array` can also see if an array exists within an array. So you can simply do this:

```
if (!in_array($new_combination, $existing_combinations)) {
    // It's unique.
}
```

In the below outdated bit, see the note on using `sort`, if a different sequence of the same numbers isn't considered unique for your purposes.

---

**[ For Entertainment ]**

May not be the most elegant way around, but I would simply do this to keep it simple:

```
$combo_hashes = [];

// Implode the existing combos into strings.
foreach($existing as $vals) {
    $combo_hashes[] = implode(':', $vals);
}
```

Then, all you need to check with your new combo is:

```
// Check if the "hash"-string already exists.

if (!in_array( implode(':', $new_combo), $combo_hashes)) {
    // ... and we're unique.
}
```

This presumes that you consider `[1,3,2]` different from `[2,1,3]`. If they are equivalent (I don't know what your use case is), you should `sort($vals);` before you generate the check-strings.

Comment: At first I suspected but didn't bother, then I read and I understood, then I went ahead to test to be sure, and then I realized. :D `$a1 = [];
$a1[] = [1,2,3];
$a2 = [1,3,2];
if (in_array($a2, $a1)) {
 echo 'not unique';
}
else {
 echo 'is unique';
}`

Answer (score 0):

Merge all the second level arrays and run **[array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)** to get rid of the duplicate values.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how I would do this please?

Comment: He's asking about combinations, ie. the triplets. Doing what you suggest would not help in creating new unique triplets that may have some values of the old sets.